# Protect Worksheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to protect a single worksheet out of my workbook with a password using the following VBA code, since I have macros running on the worksheet I want to protect.

However there is no effect when ran - any suggestions?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'enter below statement for each worksheet


Sheet1.Protect Password:="Example" , UserInterFaceOnly:=True


End Sub
```

Also, I want to be able to protect and unprotect the sheet when needed, while also having the ability to run my macro buttons.

Comment: Are you sure it's running?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "no effect"?

Comment: @Rory the worksheet is not protected once I run the code. Cells formatted to "lock" are still editable.

Comment: Then per @TimWilliams comment, did you check the code is actually running (I assume it is in the `ThisWorkbook` module of *that* workbook)?

Comment: The code runs only once, when `ThisWorkbook` is opened, and protects the worksheet in `ThisWorkbook` that has `Sheet1` for a code name. Is that the sheet you mean to protect?

Comment: Yes, it is tied to the correct workbook. sheet 1 is the code name, but do i have to include the full name ie. Sheet1(Example Name) ??

Comment: No. `Sheet1` can only refer to the sheet with that codename in the same workbook as the code. If the code is running, then the sheet will be protected, unless there is other code that unprotects it subsequently.